# Unused private function false positive?

Tags: c++, cppcheck

With Cppcheck I get:

> Unused private function: 'Derived::Func'.

Is this a false positive?

```
#include <cstdint>

class Interface {
public:
  Interface() = default;
  virtual ~Interface() = default;
  Interface(const Interface &other) = delete;
  Interface(Interface &&other) = delete;
  auto operator=(const Interface &other) -> Interface & = delete;
  auto operator=(Interface &&other) -> Interface & = delete;

  virtual auto IFunc() -> void = 0;
};

class Derived final : public Interface {
public:
  auto IFunc() -> void override;
private:
  auto Func() -> void;

  std::uint16_t mMember{};
};

auto Derived::IFunc() -> void {
  Func();
  return;
}

auto Derived::Func() -> void {
  mMember = 42;
  return;
}
```

`Derived::Func()` should not be marked as unused because it is clearly used in `Derived::IFunc()`.

Comment: What is your command line for `cppcheck`?  I'm using v2.13.0 of cppcheck, and it is not marking that routine as unused.

Answer (score 2):

*Is this a false positive?*

Yes, it is, clearly. As you have stated, `Derived::Func` is used in `Derived::IFunc`.

Strangely, the warning disappears if you change the *declaration* (but not necessarily also the *definition*) of `Derived::IFunc` from using `auto` and the trailing return type specifier (`-> void`) to the 'old-fashioned', `void IFunc() override;`. At least, that fixes it in the [online demo](https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/demo/).

The warning also goes away if you *just* remove the definitions (out-of-class bodies) of `IFunc` and `Func`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'll switch to the old-fashioned declaration.

Comment: Don't forget to file a bug ticket, too!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt   *Warning - unused bug ticket detected!*